# inverse boolean Navision

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

Is there a more easy way to inverse a boolean instead of using a IF ELSE construction?
Normally I would use the ! infront of a boolean value. But that doesn't do the trick in Navision

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `NOT` keyword in place of `!`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example to invert a boolean variable Value:

```
PROCEDURE InvertValue(VAR Value @ Boolean;);
begin
  Value := NOT Value;
end;
```